# Using VBA IE, how to run javascript?

Tags: vba

How to run Javscript function using VBA?

this is code what i am trying :

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

marker = 0

For i = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    my_url = objShell.Windows(i).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(i).Document.Title

    If my_url Like "Website"
        Set iE = objShell.Windows(i)

        Call iE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("function(){return true}")

    End If

Next
```

Javascript Source on DOM as below :

```
submitHandler : function(form) { 
            
               //Division Check Start
               var divisionGroupId = $jq("#divisionList option:selected").val();
               if(divisionGroupId == '' || divisionGroupId == null || divisionGroupId == undefined){
                   alert("Select Division");
                   $jq("#divisionList").focus();
                   return false;
               }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't overwrite `submitHandler` using an anonymous function.

Comment: Then is there no solution ?

Comment: No solution to what?  You haven't really explained what it is you're trying to do, so I'm just guessing.  Did you try `iE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("submitHandler = function(){return true;}")` ?

Comment: Thanks Tim. you catch what i want. i want to activate JS using VBA. so I tried your code but doesn't work.

Comment: It will not work if `submitHandler` isn't a method on the global Window object - if it's a method on some other object, then you'll need to use a different approach.

Comment: hell hard for me haha cuz i'm not good at JS anyway Thank you Tim for help.